# How do you set userExtension/optional claims using the graph api?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, claims

I am writing code to set optional claims. I was successful in setting the claim using PowerShell Set-AzureADUserExtension and validate it with Get-AzureADUserExtension. But we need to set the value using the graphApi.

The graphApi call that I tried with some variations are:

```
var application = (await graphClient.Applications.Request().Filter($"appId eq '{appClientId}'").GetAsync()).SingleOrDefault();
var schemas = await graphClient.Applications[application.Id].ExtensionProperties.Request().GetAsync();
var schema = schemas.CurrentPage.Single(x => x.Name == $"extension_{appClientId.Replace("-", string.Empty)}_clShops");
await graphClient.Users[userId].Extensions.Request().AddAsync (new OpenTypeExtension
{
     ODataType = "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
     AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object> { { schema.Name, "1,2,3" } },
     ExtensionName = schema.Id    
});
```

I tried changing the values in OpenTypeExtension but I have not been able to alter the value for that user (checking with the Get-AzureADUserExtension powershell command).

My question is what graphApi function do i need to call so set the optional claim to get the same result as calling Set-AzureADUserExtension?

c# graphApi sdk version is Microsoft.Graph Version=3.35.0

Answer (score 0):

figured it out after some more tests:
optionly you can get the name using:

```
var application = (await graphClient.Applications.Request().Filter($"appId eq '{appClientId}'").GetAsync()).SingleOrDefault();
var schemas = await graphClient.Applications[application.Id].ExtensionProperties.Request().GetAsync();
var schema = schemas.CurrentPage.Single(x => x.Name.EndsWith("name of claim"));
```

or by convention (replace schema.Name with): $"extension_{appId}_{'name of claim'}"

```
await graphClient.Users[userId].Request().UpdateAsync(new Microsoft.Graph.User
        {
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { schema.Name,value}
            }
        });
```